# Show and Hide mulitple input boxes from select input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with many questions for the enduser. On a certain point in the form there is a question that has 3 alternative ways to continue the form. If option 1 is selected (for example) then DIV 1 shows.

If option 2 is selected then DIV 2 shows. I have this working. Only when a enduser makes (for example) a mistake and chooces option 1, and next option 2 to correct, DIV 1 + 2 are showed both.

What I try to achieve is when a enduser chooce option 1, and makes a mistake and chooce option 2, only the newly choosen option is showed.

```js
$(function() {

        $('#my_select').change(function() {
            $('.DIV_1').slideUp("slow");
            $('#' + $(this).val()).slideDown("slow");
        });
  
  $('#my_select').change(function() {
            $('.DIV_2').slideUp("slow");
            $('#' + $(this).val()).slideDown("slow");
        });
 
    });
```

Comment: hide them all, and show one which is selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to hide the other div when one div is shown. Following should do it:

```
$(function() {

        $('#my_select').change(function() {
            $('.DIV_1').slideUp("slow");
            $('#' + $(this).val()).slideDown("slow");
            $('.DIV_2').hide();
        });

        $('#my_select').change(function() {
            $('.DIV_2').slideUp("slow");
            $('#' + $(this).val()).slideDown("slow");
            $('.DIV_1').hide();
        });

    });
```

Comment: accordingly hide all other divs if there are multiple of them

Comment: First of all thanks for the suggestion, but it didn't work. Once a div is showed it looks likes it never want to disapair anymore :(

Comment: can you clarify on what is happening, I didn't understand the comment

Comment: When I add $('.DIV_1').hide(); and $('.DIV_2').hide(); in the next offcourse, then when I select DIV_1 this is displayed. When I select DIV_2, DIV_1 is still showed and will not hide.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle or show a demo? It should have worked

Comment: Fixed it, it was a problem with a class. Thanks for your help, with your suggestion it now works (!)